# Simplify power of KroneckerDelta

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Why doesn't Mathematica simplify the following expression:

```
FullSimplify[KroneckerDelta[x,y]^3]
```

Since `KroneckerDelta` only returns `0` or `1` the `^3` could be simply ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't employ the simplification rule suggested in another proposed answer, since it will yield incorrect answers in many cases:

```
FullSimplify[KroneckerDelta[x, y]^2 f[x, y]/KroneckerDelta[x, y]]
```

(*
f[x, y] KroneckerDelta[x, y]
*)

Correct.

But if you apply the rule proposed elsewhere,

```
rule = KroneckerDelta[x_, y_]^n_ /; n > 0 -> KroneckerDelta[x, y];
```

to the numerator and denomiator:

```
myg[x, y] = KroneckerDelta[x, y]^2 f[x, y];
myh[x, y] = KroneckerDelta[x, y];
```

as here,

```
mynewg[x, y] = myg[x, y] /. rule;
mynewh[x, y] = myh[x, y] /. rule;
```

then the original term becomes

```
FullSimplify[mynewg[x, y]/mynewh[x, y]]
```

(*
f[x, y]
*)

Incorrect.

In short:  leave the powers of the `KroneckerDelta` unaltered.

Comment: You should not apply the rule before the end of operation. `rule = KroneckerDelta[x_, y_]^n_ /; n > 0 -> KroneckerDelta[x, y];
myg[x, y] = KroneckerDelta[x, y]^2 f[x, y];
myh[x, y] = KroneckerDelta[x, y];
myg[x, y]/myh[x, y] /. rule `yields `f[x, y] KroneckerDelta[x, y] `correct.

Answer (score 3):

One method is to use the fact that [`KroneckerDelta`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KroneckerDelta) is idempotent, so include this as an assumption to [`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify):

```
FullSimplify[
    KroneckerDelta[x,y]^3,
    KroneckerDelta[x,y]==KroneckerDelta[x,y]^2
]
```

> KroneckerDelta[x, y]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does not. If you need to actually simplify some expressions containing powers of Kroneker deltas you might want to use this rule:

```
rule = KroneckerDelta[x_, y_]^n_ /; n > 0 -> KroneckerDelta[x, y];
```

acting as follows:

```
    KroneckerDelta[a, b]^3 /. rule

(*   KroneckerDelta[a, b]   *)
```

Have fun!